# Post-build arguments to batch script fails to convert build parameter

Tags: batch-file, azure, tfs, build

I'm using TFS 2013 and am building an Azure Cloud Service project that I want to package with Nuget so that I can publish to Octopus Deploy.  I can't use octopack, because at the moment this is not supported.  I'm trying to pass TFS parameters into a post-build batch script so that I can run nuget with -version parameters (which should change with each build).

The problem I'm having is that the batch script does not recognise the TFS build parameters.  for example, in the script I want to pass an argument **version** $(TeamProject)-1.0.0$(Rev:.r), that would give the script the version to set in the package name.

The full nuget package call in the script is:

%nugetPath% push %packagePath%\Veedyo.%version%.nupkg

Passing this into the post-build script path works:

$/Application1/MAIN/Source/.NET/Application1.Package/package.cmd

This is because the source control path is translated into an actual path just after the build completes (and I can see the real path in the log).

However, the **Post-build script arguments** property in the build, doesn't convert this "$(TeamProject)"-1.0.0"$(Rev:.r)" to the desired value.  this leads to an error executing the batch script:

*Exception Message: TF270015: 'package.cmd' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details*

So, does anyone have any idea how to convert add build parameter to the post-build script arguments property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These macros are not available when you run the script. You can use one the the TF_BUILD environment variables listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx).

Probably, you are looking for `TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`, or maybe you have to extract the data you are looking for; in this latter case Powershell can be simpler to use than cmd.exe interpreter.

Comment: Should the parameters be added to the batch script like this "$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)"?

Comment: These are environment variables; from cmd interpreter `%TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER%`, in Powershell `$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`